# How do I mock a class in a Python unit test?

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I have a class:

```
class A:
    __init__(self):
        self.b = B()

   def is_authorized(self)
      name = self.b.get_name()

      if name == 'admin':
          return True
      else:
          return False
```

I'd like to write a unit test to test the `is_authorized` method. The problem is that it requires an instance of the `B` class which is very complicated to construct in isolation as it requires network connections and other stuff. How can I mock this class and provide something that just has the `get_name` method. So that I can create the `A` class and test the method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By use [`mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) library you can patch `B` class and replace it by a `MagicMock()` object. `mock` library was designed exactly to do these kind of works and to break hard dependencies from problematic object or real resources.

In your simple example the complete test will be:

**module_a.py**

```
class B():
    def __init__(self):
        print("The awful B class!!!")

    def get_name(self):
        print("The awful B.get_name() method!!!")


class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B()

    def is_authorized(self):
        name = self.b.get_name()
        if name == 'admin':
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

**module_a_test.py**

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from module_a import A


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    # patch B class in a_module by a MagicMock instance
    # mock_b_constructor passed to test method
    @patch("module_a.B")
    def test_a(self, mock_b_constructor):
        # B() return value will be the B() instance assigned to a.b property
        mock_b = mock_b_constructor.return_value
        # Now start test:
        a = A()
        # Ok! b is our mock...
        self.assertIs(a.b, mock_b)
        # Not authorized
        self.assertFalse(a.is_authorized())
        mock_b.get_name.return_value = 'admin'
        # Yeah!!! we are admin
        self.assertTrue(a.is_authorized())
        # Sanity check
        mock_b.get_name.return_value = 'guest'
        self.assertFalse(a.is_authorized())
```

[Patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-patchers) will live just for your test method context. That is a simple and straightforward example of how to use mocks and patches from `mock` but the real cases can be little more complicated.

Answer (score -4):

Create a mock class for B, e.g.:

```
class MockB(object):
    def get_name(self):
        return 'admin'
```

Then, in your test case, wrap A in a class that inits with MockB instead of regular B:

```
class TestA(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = MockB()
```

Though, to be honest, I'm not sure what that proves.